# How to remove subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to get all count for all orders, which was passed to query, even for null. I have developed such kind of query in SQL Server 2008R2:

```
SELECT COUNT(UserId), b.OrderId
FROM @OrderList b
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT pat_base.UserId, prov_list.OrderId
    FROM Users pat_base
    LEFT JOIN Assetments hlth_asmt ON hlth_asmt.UserId = pat_base.UserId
        AND hlth_asmt.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    LEFT JOIN Logs proc_log ON proc_log.UserId = pat_base.UserId 
        AND proc_log.PLDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    LEFT JOIN Encounter med_enc_log ON med_enc_log.UserId = pat_base.UserId
        AND med_enc_log.EncounterDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    LEFT JOIN @OrderList prov_list ON
        hlth_asmt.OrderId = prov_list.OrderId
        OR proc_log.OrderId = prov_list.OrderId
        OR med_enc_log.OrderId = prov_list.OrderId
    WHERE hlth_asmt.UserId IS NOT NULL
        OR proc_log.UserId IS NOT NULL
    OR med_enc_log.UserId IS NOT NULL
) a ON a.OrderId=b.OrderId
GROUP BY b.OrderId
```

If I remove joined subquery, order is being cut with many-to-many relation. Is it possible to replace subquery with join?

P.S. Here is output now:

```
            OrderId
----------- -----------
8           10001
0           10003
```

Output without subquery:

```
            OrderId
----------- -----------
8           10001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change

```
LEFT JOIN @OrderList prov_list ON
```

to

```
RIGHT JOIN @OrderList prov_list ON
```

if you use left join you filter out orders wich are in @OrderList but dont have expected user

so the query would be like

```
SELECT COUNT(UserId), prov_list.OrderId
    FROM Users pat_base
    LEFT JOIN Assetments hlth_asmt ON hlth_asmt.UserId = pat_base.UserId
        AND hlth_asmt.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    LEFT JOIN Logs proc_log ON proc_log.UserId = pat_base.UserId 
        AND proc_log.PLDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    LEFT JOIN Encounter med_enc_log ON med_enc_log.UserId = pat_base.UserId
        AND med_enc_log.EncounterDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    RIGHT JOIN @OrderList prov_list ON
        hlth_asmt.OrderId = prov_list.OrderId
        OR proc_log.OrderId = prov_list.OrderId
        OR med_enc_log.OrderId = prov_list.OrderId
    WHERE hlth_asmt.UserId IS NOT NULL
        OR proc_log.UserId IS NOT NULL
    OR med_enc_log.UserId IS NOT NULL
group by prov_list.OrderId
```

edit

yeah, that means that those rows were filtered out in where clause

change it to

```
WHERE hlth_asmt.UserId IS NOT NULL
OR proc_log.UserId IS NOT NULL
OR med_enc_log.UserId IS NOT NULL
OR pat_base IS NULL
```

but i think what it means, is that you have inconsistent data within db

Comment: yeah, that means that those rows were filtered out in where clause

Comment: But I need to get count, if there is null in intermediate tables Encounter, Logs, Assetments. I'm really stuck with that.

Comment: Man, real thanks to you. I've just removed WHERE clause, and everything begin to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can return the result from a single query, but I'd recommend not using a join.  Instead, remove your outer query, and change to inner query to use a windowing function on the count.  So your SELECT clause would be something similar to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   pat_base.UserId,
   prov_list.OrderId,
   COUNT(pat_base.UserId) OVER (PARTITION BY prov_list.OrderId) as UserCount
```

Comment: Is it possible with many-to-many relation? 'Cause here is missed intermediate tables, there is no mention to OrderId in Users table.

Comment: You would keep the rest of your query the same, so all of your intermediate tables would be included

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try that later, because now all that stuff just need to work.